# NumberFormatException and TypeMismatchException for using propertyPlaceholderConfigurer in xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am using a List being initialized in spring.xml. I need to use propertyPlaceholderConfigurer to loose-couple initial values in pointList.cfg.properties file.

this is spring.xml code:

```
<bean id="parentTriangle" class="edu.akarimin.koushik.Triangle" autowire="byName" init-method="myInit" destroy-method="cleanUp">
    <property name="pointList">
        <list>
            <ref bean="pointA" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="triangle" class="edu.akarimin.koushik.Triangle" parent="parentTriangle">
    <property name="pointList">
        <list merge="true">
            <ref bean="pointB" />
            <ref bean="pointC" />
            <ref bean="pointD" />

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="pointA" class="edu.akarimin.koushik.Point">
    <property name="x" value="${pointA.pointX}" />
    <property name="y" value="${pointA.pointY}" />
</bean>
<bean id="pointB" class="edu.akarimin.koushik.Point">
    <property name="x" value="${pointB.pointX}" />
    <property name="y" value="${pointB.pointY}" />
</bean>
<bean id="pointC" class="edu.akarimin.koushik.Point">
    <property name="x" value="${pointC.pointX}" />
    <property name="y" value="${pointC.pointY}" />
</bean>

<bean id="pointD" class="edu.akarimin.koushik.Point">
    <property name="x" value="${pointD.pointX}" />
    <property name="y" value="${pointD.pointY}" />
</bean>
<bean id="pointE" class="edu.akarimin.koushik.Point">
    <property name="x" value="${pointE.pointX}" />
    <property name="y" value="${pointE.pointY}" />
</bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.propertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:pointList.cfg.properties</value>
            </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Triangle Class code is:

package edu.akarimin.koushik;
public class Triangle{

```
  private List<Point> pointList;

  public void draw(){
      for (Point point : pointList) {
        System.out.println("Point= (" +point.getX()+ ","+point.getY()+")");
    }

public void myInit(){
    System.out.println("MyInit method called for Triangle");
}
public void cleanUp(){
    System.out.println("CleanUp method called for Triangle");
```

}

And main method is:

```
public class DrawingApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");      
    Triangle triangle = context.getBean("triangle", Triangle.class);                                 
    triangle.draw();    
}
```

}

class Point is:

```
public class Point {
private int x;
private int y;
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

Any ideas to fix the problem ?

Comment: pointList.cfg.properties contains:

pointA.pointX=0
pointA.pointY=0
pointB.pointX=25
pointB.pointY=25
pointC.pointX=100
pointC.pointY=30
pointD.pointX=-30
pointD.pointY=-190
pointE.pointX=89
pointE.pointY=-100

Comment: can you show us your Point class?

Comment: I have updated my post, Point class included.